# Self-hosted Azure DevOps build agent with "pull" instead of "push" mechanism (no DMZ)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, devops

I would like to set up a CI pipeline from Azure DevOps to a local server.
Is it possible to set up a self-hosted build agent that will not be reachable over the internet? In other words, have the build agent check for new commits on Azure DevOps periodically ("pull"), instead of Azure DevOps notifying the build agent ("push")? Because I would prefer not to have the build server in the DMZ/reachable over the internet.

I believe this at least used to be possible when it was still called "TFS Online", but I don't know how set this up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline agents already work that way; they do not listen for incoming traffic, but rather periodically poll Azure DevOps. They simply need outbound port 443 open so they can communicate with the Azure DevOps platform. No inbound ports need to be open. I'm not sure what leads you to believe they work differently.

You'll need to ask a new question with more specificity if you're having some sort of issue configuring your agents.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding with my colleague about which ports should be opened. For some reason, dev.azure.com:443 (outbound) specifically was being blocked on the server, while other outbound connections were fine and I thought that my colleague was asking me to unblock port 443 for inbound traffic. Thanks for your answer!